# How can i search in c# list with one of its information?

Tags: c#, list, inheritance, search, console

so I have a list of objects in my program that objects in it have (name, last name, id, house, etc.)
I want to create a method called search that lets me find a specific object only with its name. I want to print out the information after search.
(i have one parent class caled wizard and two child classes. one for teachers and one for students(WizardToBe).)

`List<WizardTobe> WizardStudents = new List<WizardTobe>();`

I received all the information needed below using Readline so all of these are user input.
and all of my codes are in a while loop.

```
                        string studentname = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Your last name?");
                        string studentlast = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("And you my child, which house are you from?");
                        string studentHouse = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("And may i know your wizard ID?");
                        string studentWizID = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("And what creature is your lovely Familiar?");
                        string studentFamiliar = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("What is your student ID?");
                        string babywizID = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("sorry this is taking long. Lastly! in School year, what year are you curently in?");
                        string yearschool = Console.ReadLine();
                        WizardStudents.Add(new WizardTobe(studentname, studentlast, studentWizID, studentHouse, studentFamiliar, babywizID, yearschool));
```

I tried to name the object that I want to add to my list as "studentname" which I received with Readline. but I faced another error...
what should I do ? :(

my classes are these:
my parent class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace HogwartsSignUp
{
    public class Wizard
    {
        string name;
        string lastname;
        string wizID;
        string house;

        //teacher
        private string yearclass;
        private string workID;

        //students
        private string familiar;
        private string studentID;
        private string studentyear;




        public Wizard(string name, string lastname, string wizID, string house, string familiar, string studentID, string studentyear)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.lastname = lastname;
            this.wizID = wizID;
            this.house = house;
            this.studentID = studentID;
            this.familiar = familiar;
            this.studentyear = studentyear;
        }
        public Wizard(string name, string lastname, string wizID, string house, string yearclass, string workID)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.lastname = lastname;
            this.wizID = wizID;
            this.house = house;
            this.workID = workID;
            this.yearclass = yearclass;
        }
        public void showStudentInfo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("They are a Hogwarts student! Here's the information of them:");
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}     Last name: {1}       House: {2}        Year: {3}      Familiar: {4}", name, lastname,house,studentyear,familiar);
        }

        public void showTeacherInfo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("They are a Hogwarts teacher! Here's the information of them:");
            Console.WriteLine("Name:{0}     Last Name:{1}        House:{2}      Teacher of the class: {3}", name, lastname, house, yearclass);
        }
    }
}
```

my child class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace HogwartsSignUp
{
    public class WizardTobe : Wizard
    {
        string magicwand;
        string sportinterest;
        string hobby;


        public WizardTobe(string name, string lastname, string wizID, string house, string familiar, string studentID, string studentyear) : base (name, lastname,  wizID, house, familiar, studentID, studentyear)
        {

        }
     
    }
}
```

Comment: `WizardStudents.Where(s => s.name == somename);` may work, dont know as you've not posted the any of these classes.

Comment: yes i want to find a student  with their names.

Comment: i want to search in my list with only their name typed by user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Language Integrated Query to search through the list. Following is the link to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/

Here is a sample console application using your code that illustrates this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Console_Example
{
    public class WizardTobe
    {
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public string StudentLast { get; set; }
        public string StudentWizID { get; set; }
        public string StudentHouse { get; set; }        
        public string StudentFamiliar { get; set; }
        public string BabyWizID { get; set; }
        public string YearsSchool { get; set; }

        public WizardTobe(string studentName, string studentLast, string studentWizID, string studentHouse, string studentFamiliar, string babyWizID, string yearsSchool)
        {
            StudentName = studentName;
            StudentLast = studentLast;
            StudentWizID = studentWizID;
            StudentHouse = studentHouse;            
            StudentFamiliar = studentFamiliar;
            BabyWizID = babyWizID;
            YearsSchool = yearsSchool;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<WizardTobe> WizardStudents = new List<WizardTobe>();

            string studentname = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Your last name?");
            string studentlast = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("And you my child, which house are you from?");
            string studentHouse = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("And may i know your wizard ID?");
            string studentWizID = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("And what creature is your lovely Familiar?");
            string studentFamiliar = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("What is your student ID?");
            string babywizID = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("sorry this is taking long. Lastly! in School year, what year are you curently in?");
            string yearschool = Console.ReadLine();
            WizardStudents.Add(new WizardTobe(studentname, studentlast, studentWizID, studentHouse, studentFamiliar, babywizID, yearschool));
            WizardStudents.Add(new WizardTobe("Peter","","","","","",""));
            WizardStudents.Add(new WizardTobe("Steven", "", "", "", "", "", ""));
            WizardStudents.Add(new WizardTobe("Maria", "", "", "", "", "", ""));
            WizardStudents.Add(new WizardTobe("Ashley", "", "", "", "", "", ""));

            string studentToBeSearched = "Ashley";
            Console.WriteLine($"\n\nSearching for student named {studentToBeSearched}");
            WizardTobe missingStudent = WizardStudents.Where(x => x.StudentName == studentToBeSearched).FirstOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine(missingStudent.StudentName);

            Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }        
    }
}
```

***Note: Above code is to demonstrate only the solution to the asked problem and not to demonstrate good programming practice.***

Comment: can i use this get set in my child class?

Comment: let me add my classes to my question

Comment: Yes, the line with get, set thing are called Properties in C#. Yes you can use them in your child classes. You don't have to specify classes here. Just copy my code in a Console project and run it to get the idea and then modify your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all override `ToString()` function in your `WizardTobe` class, return string with all properties you want to print.

```
public class WizardTobe
{
   public string StudentName{ get; set; }
   public string StudentLastName{ get; set; }
   ...
   public override string ToString()
   {
       return $"Student First Name: {StudentName}: Last Name: {StudentLastName}";
   } 
}
```

In your program where you want print this information use `.Where()` or `.First()` or `.Single()` as per your requirement.

I am using `.Where()` as there might be multiple students with same name and lets print all students which satisfy this condition

```
var results = WizardStudents.Where(s => s.name == somename);
foreach(var result in results)
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

[MSDN :How to override the ToString method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method#:%7E:text=%20To%20override%20the%20ToString%20method%20in%20your,the%20class%20in%20addition%20to%20the...%20More%20)